# Does there exist some linear factor for every quadratic such that their product's $x^2$ and $x$ terms disappear

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, integers

Can any quadratic with integer coefficients be multiplied by some linear factor, also with integer coefficients, such that the coefficients of the product's $x^2$ and $x$ terms are both zero and the coefficient of the $x^3$ is nonzero and the constant term can be any integer?

Alternatively, for readability, is there always some $px+q$ such that for any quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ with $a,p \ne 0$ and $a,b,c,p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$, $(ax^2+bx+c)(px+q) = apx^3+cq$ ?

I tried searching for the question online but it looks like it was too specific to already have been asked (unless I'm not looking hard enough).

What I've tried so far is that if I have the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ and the linear factor $px+q$ with $a,p \ne 0$ and $a,b,c,p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$, multiplying these two expressions gives us $(ax^2+bx+c)(px+q)=apx^3+(aq+bp)x^2+(bq+cp)x+cq$ and now we have the following statements and equations:

$$ap\text{ is a nonzero integer}$$
$$aq+bp = 0$$
$$bq+cp = 0$$
$$cq \text{ is an integer}$$

The first and last statements are redundant due to the fact that $a,b,c,p,$ and $q$ are all integers and if $a$ or $p$ were $0$, then $ax^2+bx+c$ would not be a quadratic and $px+q$ would be a constant. This means that we only need to solve the following system of equations:

$$aq+bp = 0$$
$$bq+cp = 0$$

Multiplying both sides of the top equation by $q$ and both sides of the bottom equation by $p$, we get that $aq^2+bpq = 0 = bpq+cp^2$ and so $aq^2=cp^2$. Rearranging, we get that $\dfrac{a}{c}=\dfrac{p^2}{q^2} = \left(\dfrac{p}{q}\right)^2$. Does this mean that such a linear factor only exists when $\dfrac{a}{c}$ is the square of a rational number?

I'm sorry if this was hard to read, English is my first language and I'm still bad at it.

Comment: Regardless of the integer constraints, assuming $a \neq 0$ and solving $aq+bp=0, bq+cp=0$ means you need either $p=q=0$ or $b^2=ac$. On the other hand, if $a,b,c$ are integers that satisfy $b^2=ac$ and $a\neq 0$, you can choose $p=a$ and $q=-b$.

Comment: @Michael I understand that the system of equations is true when either of those two conditions are met, but why are those the only conditions that are sufficient for the system of equations to have solutions?

Comment: Did you try solving the two equations I specified? You necessarily arrive at either $p=0$ or $b^2=ac$.  Just substitute $q = -bp/a$ into the second equation.

Comment: Yeah, I did, you're right my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $a,b,c$ are integers and $a \neq 0$, we want to find $p,q$ so that $p\neq 0$ and
$$(ax^2 + bx + c)(px+q) = apx^3 + cq$$
where $ap$ is an integer and $cq$ is an integer.

**Claim:** The necessary and sufficient condition is $b^2=ac$.

Proof:

- Necessity:  We need $aq+bp=0$ and $bq+cp=0$.  Substituting $q=-bp/a$ into the second equation gives that either $p=0$ or $b^2=ac$.  Since $p\neq 0$ we must have $b^2=ac$.
- Sufficiency: If $b^2=ac$ then we can choose $p=a$ and $q=-b$.

$\Box$

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you.